# how do I access a resource file from a dependent jar?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have an android application that has a dependent library I created, referenced in build.gradle via compile {artifact_name}.  The library needs to access a resource file in its resources dir(src/main/resources).  Here is what I want to accomplish, but can't:

```
URL url = helper.class.getClassLoader().getResource("myfile.json");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(url.getPath());
```

myfile.json is in src/main/java/resources of my library.  this led to an app crash saying "jar:file:/data/app/com.my.app/base.apk!/myfile.json" not found when trying to create the FileReader.

However, it can be found if I run it in a client class in the library itself.

Comment: Android doesn't use jar file resources.   Until recently (maybe a year ago) you couldn't do it at all-  if your project had resources it needed to be included as source in your app.  Now you can, but you need to use an android library module, and probably put the resources in there rather than in the jar itself.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what you're gaining by trying to use JAR resources as opposed to just about anything else (Android resources, Android assets, downloading something from a server, etc.). JAR resources have been funky on Android from the beginning, and I rarely see them used successfully.

Comment: question revised to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated (I have some more time to give full answer)

In your case `ClassLoader` of helper class have an access to your file (there are why you get `"jar:file:/data/app/com.my.app/base.apk!/myfile.json"` in your `FileReader` instance).

But `FileReader` don't understand full-qualified `URL`s (only `URL`s with scheme `file:` or without any scheme, but you have outer scheme `jar:` - file accessible from jar file).

To read data in this case you should1 use combination of [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) and [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
ClassLoader cl = helper.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("myfile.json");
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

PS <s>in common situations you don't need access `ClassLoader` directly - `Class` will access it by itself. Only rare cases should use access to `ClassLoader` and in this situations you should really understand `Class`es and `ClassLoader`s very clear.</s>
I found out some usefull information: `Class`es method (both `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream`) checks file only in same package while `ClassLoader`s methods checks (additionally) at root path (as I remember some of them checks in both places and today I checked that Class don't check root of jar file).

Comment: thanks, but this does not work, the inputstream turns out null.  ive updated my question be to clearer.

Comment: Hmm... I've found some additional info... In your case you rightly used `ClassLoader`'s method... I'll write it in answer now.